# (Django) Displaying multiple generated forms (unknown quantity) in the view, and retrieving their results?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm currently attempting to display a set of generated forms into the view. So take the following view, for example (as part of a `TemplateView` class):

```py
def get(self, request, id):
    df = create_dataframe(User.objects.get(user=request.user.username))
    context = generate_context_forms(df=df, user=request.user.username)

    return authentication_check(
         request=request, template_name=self.template_name, context=context
    )
```

In essence, the `create_dataframe` function generates some relevant calculations using some user-inputted data, and that data designates how many forms I will be generating for the user. The `generate_context_forms` function utilizes that `DataFrame` to generate the context for the user. The `authentication_check` is a basic function that acts like `render` but with some extra things. Typically, a `context` will look like so:

```py
context = {
    'general': GeneralForm,
    'specific1': SpecificForm,
    'specific2': SpecificForm,
    ...
}
```

To `n` amounts of `SpecificForm`. What I am trying to do is display all of the specific forms to the user without causing loss of control. All the forms will be submitted by a single "submit" button, and after submission, I must gather all of the data they individually submitted. With the context above, I do not know how I would iterate through all the `specific` forms in the context.

Another attempt I did was to simply add the specific forms to a list:

```py
context = {
    'general': GeneralForm,
    'specific': [SpecificForm, SpecificForm, ...],
}
```

But it seems that when I loop through them within my view:

```html
{% for form in specific %}
  <div class="ui fluid card">
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">{{ form.instance.prompt }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="extra content">
      {{ form|crispy }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

What ends up happening is that the radio-button of each generated form interacts with the other. In other words, within all of the 'specific form' there is a selection of `Yes/No` radio buttons for a question, but it seems that all of those radio buttons unselect each other (independent of the form). This is also a solution that I am unsure how to pull the user submission data from afterward.

Any help would be appreciated on this topic, as it's something I've been a bit stuck on for the last few days, and I can't find any relevant information online for "generated forms."

Comment: I had a similar issue and I had to set a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) on each form so that I could tell them apart when handling the POST request.  Not sure whether it will work with crispy forms but it's worth a try.

Comment: @FiddleStix Ah, I see. The `prefix` is set within the `Form` class. I'll give this a shot on the form generation, and then use a `for-loop` in the `post` portion of the `TemplateView` with a `try-except` block to loop through em. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try to implement a solution using [formsets or model-formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) for your 'SpecificForm' ?

Comment: I glossed over `Formsets` in my research to figure out this problem, but I think this might just be a good idea. I'm gonna give this a shot, thank you.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you @Niark!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I needed to do after all. In the `forms.py` file, I had the following:

```py
class FeedbackSpecificForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reaction = forms.CharField(
        label="What is your reaction to this feedback?",
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea,
    )
    awareness = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Were you aware that you used this cue to make your rating?",
        required=True,
        choices=[("yes", "Yes"), ("no", "No")],
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    )
    why = forms.CharField(
        label="Why do you think you utilized this cue to make your rating?",
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = FeedbackSpecific
        fields = ["reaction", "awareness", "why"]
```

What I needed to do was simply create a model form set (in the `forms.py`):

```py
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
FeedbackSpecificFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    FeedbackSpecific, form=FeedbackSpecificForm
)
```

Which then allowed me, in the `generate_context_forms()` function, to create a list of `FeedbackSpecific`:

```py
specifics = []
for prompt in prompts:
    prompt = f ' ... some stuff here ...'
    specific = FeedbackSpecific(feedback=feedback, prompt=prompt)
    specific.save()
    specifics.append(specific)
```

And then generate my `Formset`:

```py
specificFormSet = FeedbackSpecificFormSet(queryset=specifics)
```

Which I returned to my view and sent it into the context:

```py
generalForm, specificFormSet = generate_user_form(request.user, feedback)

return render(
    request,
    self.template_name,
    {"generalForm": generalForm, "specificFormSet": specificFormSet},
)
```

Within the view, I simply iterated through the `specificFormSet`:

```py
{% for form in specificFormSet %}
    <div class="ui fluid card">
      <div class="content">
        <a class="header">{{ form.instance.prompt }}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="extra content">
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It was easier than I thought it would've been. The documentation in the `ModelForm` is frankly a bit confusing. Hopefully this helps someone out.